# Remove a part of chapter title from sidebar href and page header

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, header-footer, bookmarks

My chapter title is "{some special symbol} some text" and that special symbol does not show up properly in the sidebar clickable menu (in the compiled pdf file) as well as in the page header. I was wondering if it is possible to remove that symbol from the side and the header while keeping it in the ToC and in the chapter title?

Sample pdf: http://www.scribd.com/doc/118926256/sample-pdf

Problem: the customized progress bar shows up in the sidebar as text, the EightFlowerPetalRemoved symbol shows up in the page header as letter Y. Both progress bar and the special symbol show up properly in TOC and the chapter page.

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}  

\usepackage{type1cm}  
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % clickable TOC
\usepackage{ifthen}            % ifthen command
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{progressbar}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{color,calc}

\newcommand{\threeS}{\progressbar[subdivisions=5, linecolor=blue, tickscolor=blue, filledcolor=gray, emptycolor=white, heightr=0.7, width=1.2em, rou=0.3]{0.6}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{\threeS \EightFlowerPetalRemoved chapter title}

insert a long text here so it spans to the next page....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wellcome to tex.se!!! Can you please give some more information about that special symbol you are trying to include in your document? It would also be very convinient if you coul a sample of your code!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added the sample pdf and the latex code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol macros need `\protect` for the table of contents and the headers. Only the second symbol is available in Unicode, thus the first can be removed for the bookmarks with `\texorpdfstring`. The new option `psdextra` of `hyperref` supports `\EightFlowerPetalRemoved` directly. Also I recommend package `bookmark` to get the bookmarks faster updated:

```
\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]
\usepackage{bookmark}

\chapter{%
  \texorpdfstring{\protect\threeS}{}%
  \protect\EightFlowerPetalRemoved
  chapter title}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works exactly the way I wanted :)